# REGEX Need to find numbers after string but exclude string searched on

Tags: javascript, regex

Hey I'm trying to split a string of words so I can grab the full size of the image.

Right now I have "/perch/resources/res-img13-w368h368.jpg"

I want to remove the '-w368h38" coming after the img13, so it would turn out like "/perch/resources/res-img13.jpg"

I've spent a while trying to figure out the regex, but I am quite new to regex and dont really know what im doing. 
Any help would be awesome!

Comment: 1. Provide several examples of image-names. 2. Put the regex you already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question and the explanation contradicts. I will go with the explanation.

```
var str = "/perch/resources/res-img13-w368h368.jpg";    
var regexResult = str.exec(/(.*)(-w\d*h\d*)(.*)/);
var result = regexResult[1] + regexResult[3];
```

The part `(.*)` means match any character and group them. Grouping (enclosing parts with parentheses) makes that part accessible later.

`(-w\d*h\d*)` groups a literal char "-", a "w" char immediately after "-", none or infinite digits after "w", character "h" and again, none or infinite digits.

Final `(.*)` groups the rest of string.

When the function exec is called the result is an array with the groups we specified:

```
[
  "/perch/resources/res-img13-w368h368.jpg", //First element is the whole match 
  "/perch/resources/res-img13", //Our first group
  "-w368h368", //Our second group
  ".jpg" //Our final group
]
```

Comment: That regex was way more difficult than what I had thought. Thanks so much! That worked for me so now im able to get the image without the prefix added on!

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex [`^((?:\/.+)+\/.+)-w(\d+)h(\d+)(\..+)`](https://regex101.com/r/zU2q4J/2) and tell me if that's what you're searching for. Group 1 matches `/perch/resources/res-img13`, group 2 matches the width, group 3 matches the height and group 4 matches the extension.

```
var input = "something format_abc";
var regex = /^((?:\/.+)+\/.+)-w(\d+)h(\d+)(\..+)/g;
var match = regex.exec(input);
console.log("WIDTH: " + match[2] + "px , HEIGHT: " + match[3] + "px");
```